# continued fraction of $\sqrt{10k+3}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Could you please help me to find the continued fraction of

$$\sqrt{10k+3}.$$

Where $k$ is a positive integer.

All the best,

Comment: By that you mean $k = \sqrt{10 k + 3}$? If so, square both sides and use quadratic formula.

Comment: No. I want to find continued fraction $\sqrt{10k+3}$ , where $k$ is positive integer.

Comment: There is no general way to find this. It depends on the value of $k$.

Comment: What about $\sqrt {10k+\text{the continued fraction for } 3}$?

Comment: You may find [OEIS sequence 3285](https://oeis.org/A003285) "Period of continued fraction for square root of n" of interest.

Comment: There are some patterns for which the continued fraction really does follow a consistent pattern, such as $\sqrt{k^2 - 1}$ or $\sqrt {k^2 + 1}.$ They have a $k^2$ in them. The ones you ask about have no pattern at all.

Comment: You might want to search "richaud-degert type".  For carefully chosen $k$, you can find some patterns.

Comment: I just know k is odd positive integer.

Comment: Do all numerators need to be $1$? A simple continued fraction?

Comment: @CleytonMuto Yes. A simple.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{equation*}
x+1=\sqrt{10k+3}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
x^{2}+2x+1=10k+3
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
x^{2}+2x=10k+2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
x\left(x+2\right)=10k+2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
x=\dfrac{10k+2}{2+x}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
x=\dfrac{10k+2}{2+\dfrac{10k+2}{2+\dfrac{10k+2}{2+\dots}}}
\end{equation*}
Then,
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{10k+3}=1+x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{10k+3}=1+\dfrac{10k+2}{2+\dfrac{10k+2}{2+\dfrac{10k+2}{2+\dots}}}
\end{equation*}

Comment: (+1) What was the motivation behind consider $x+1$ equal to the expression?

Comment: Although $k$ is a positive integer, the similarity to $\sqrt{3}=1+0.73205080\dots$ is undeniable. It's actually possible to add bigger values to $x$, but as the continued fraction appears from a recursive application, making the recursion $x\left(x+2\right)$ simple, i.e., tightly close, $x\left(x+2\right)+1$ is advisable.

Comment: `the similarity to` $\sqrt{3}=1+0.73205080\cdots$ `is undeniable`- Can you explain this statement? Why they need to be similar?